# Find rows with same elements (not caring about order)

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

If I have a dataframe with duplicated rows we can find out with [`duplicated`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/removing-duplicated-rows-data-frame-in-r). See here:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3))
b <- c("B", "B","C")
df <-data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = F)
df
  a b
1 A B
2 A B
3 A C

duplicated(df)
FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Here row 1 and 2 are identical. But what I need is a function that tells me that two (or more) columns contain the same elements, regardless of their order. Such a df could look like that:

```
df[2, ] <- df[2, 2:1]
df
  a b
1 A B
2 B A
3 A C
```

If we do not care about order rows 1 and 2 are still same, because both have A and B. So my expected output is for the latter df:

```
magicfunction(df)
FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: `duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))` Also check the linked section of the post there are lot of related posts with different ways.

Comment: @RonakShah Wow, my question about duplicates is a duplicate of a duplicate. This is ironic. Thank you for your help!